# Extract Earliest Date from Postgres jsonb array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

Suppose I have a jsonb array in a postgres column like

```
[{"startDate": "2019-09-01"}, {"startDate": "2019-07-22"}, {"startDate": "2019-08-08"}]
```

Is there a way to extract the earliest startDate from the jsonb array? I have tried using jsonb_array_elements but don't see how to loop through all the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a scalar sub-query

```
select (select (e.element ->> 'startDate')::date as start_date
        from jsonb_array_elements(t.the_column) as e.element
        order by start_date desc
        limit 1) as start_date
from the_table t
```

You need to replace `the_table` and `the_column` with the actual table and column name you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `MIN()` aggregation after casting the derived value to `date` :

```
SELECT MIN((elm ->> 'startDate')::date)
  FROM t
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsdata) AS j(elm)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d3ef854d87c10350538c310bf8b60d66)</kbd>

Comment: Very nice idea!